# How can i edit the hosts file on macbook?

Tags: macos

I would like to modify the hosts file on my Mac; however, I am encountering permission issues that prevent me from doing so.

I have attempted to open the file using the 'sudo' command, but when I try to save the changes, I encounter an error indicating that I lack the necessary permissions.

Additionally, I have disabled System Integrity Protection (SIP), but unfortunately, this has not resolved the issue.

Comment: Have you tried opening it from a text editor?

Comment: @AudunHilden yes. Same problem. He asks me to duplicate.

Comment: Try `sudo nano hosts`, and enter your password, you should be able to edit and save it. Type your changes, then hit `ctrl + o` and `enter` to save, and `ctrl + x` to exit out of `nano`.

Comment: @Aeronautix, as I mentioned earlier in the text, I am unable to make edits to the file using the 'sudo' or 'nano' commands. Whenever I attempt to do so, I am confronted with an error indicating insufficient permissions. I appreciate your response, but I kindly request that you review the text before providing assistance in the future. Thank you.

Comment: What does `ls -l hosts` give you? Mine is `-rw-r--r--`.

Comment: @Aeronautix -rw-r--r--@ 1 root  wheel  4154 Aug  8 16:51 /etc/hosts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.

I entered the following commands in the terminal, and now it's working:

```
sudo chflags nouchg /etc/hosts
sudo chflags noschg /etc/hosts
```